# ¿Se puede hacer que el valor de time_stamp, predeterminado en mysql, obvie los segundos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un control de picada, y el indice de la tabla debe ser el nº de empleado + time_stamp, pero no quiero que aparezcan los segundos, y así evitar que se pique dos veces en menos de un minuto, así que necesito que la tabla guarde solo fecha y horas y minutos, de forma predeterminada desde el mysql

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así, a ver qué tal:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    id_usuario,DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%m')
  ) stamp  
  FROM usuarios;
```

Si necesitas más ayuda, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo la estructura de tus tablas con Exportar desde phpMyAdmin y déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, sí, esa opción la tenia contemplada, pero me interesaría que fuera el valor predeterminado de la tabla en mysql, sustituir Current_Timestamp, pero sin el valor de los segundos.

Comment: Pues habrá que definir un disparador que, tras cada `INSERT`, le asigne esa marca a cada registro horario. Lo dicho: aporta tus tablas y te indico cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ya lo resolví, me estuve planteando el disparador de mysql, pero tiene ciertos problemillas al cambiar de servidor de bbdd, así que hice conversión reconversión de cadenas y recorté los 3 últimos caracteres, y por fin conseguí quitar los segundos del timestamp. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Bueno, puede ser otra opción. Aunque si haces un `UPDATE` en PHP justo después del `INSERT` obtienes el mismo efecto que con el disparador. Te animo a responderte a ti mismo con lo que buscabas, pues tal vez pueda ayudar a alguien más en tu misma situación.

Comment: Ok, en resumen estas dos sentencia arregló lo que buscaba, la primera me da la hora en Madrid, y la segunda formatea a día mes año, hora y minuto con 0 delante si es de una cifra.   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $fec=date('d-m-Y g:i', time());